# Django haystack indexing after new entity added

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I'm wondering what operation should invoke after adding new entity to database to make this entity searchable with haystack:

- should I only update the index?
- should I rebuild the whole index?

What's problematic is that new entities will be added frequently and there might be potentially large amount of entities in db.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure why somebody voted to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're adding new rows to your database then `update_index` should be enough.

From the [haystack docs](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchindex_api.html#keeping-the-index-fresh):

> The conventional method is to use `SearchIndex` in combination with cron
>   jobs. Running a `./manage.py update_index` every couple hours will keep
>   your data in sync within that timeframe and will handle the updates in
>   a very efficient batch.

If you added a new *field* to your search index, then you would need to run `rebuild_index`:

> If you have an existing `SearchIndex` and you add a new field to it,
>   Haystack will add this new data on any updates it sees after that
>   point. However, this will not populate the existing data you already
>   have.
>
> In order for the data to be picked up, you will need to run
>   `./manage.py rebuild_index`. This will cause all backends to rebuild the
>   existing data already present in the quickest and most efficient way.